# How do I get jabber.el to not show the user icons?

Tags: emacs, xmpp

I just set up jabber.el to use with my gmail account, and I want to make it stop showing the user icons in the roster. I just want to see the basic text. How do I do that?

Answer (score 6):

Just found the answer. You have to remove %a from the jabber-roster-line-format string to get rid of the avatar.

Answer (score 5):

Here is me jabber.el settings:

```
(custom-set-variables
  ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(jabber-auto-reconnect t)
 '(jabber-avatar-verbose nil)
 '(jabber-vcard-avatars-retrieve nil)
 '(jabber-chat-buffer-format "*-jabber-%n-*")
 '(jabber-history-enabled t)
 '(jabber-mode-line-mode t)
 '(jabber-roster-buffer "*-jabber-*")
 '(jabber-roster-line-format " %c %-25n %u %-8s (%r)")
 '(jabber-show-offline-contacts nil))
```

It removes avatars and status line from roster. Also enables history and auto-reconnect. And hides offline contacts. If you need them - you can use `M-x jabber-roster-toggle-offline-display`. Or, and its shorten alittle jabber buffer names...

Answer (score 2):

You can also tell it not to download them at all by setting `jabber-vcard-avatars-retrieve` to `nil`.